# Async method await keyword doesn't suspend to calling method

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library, c#-5.0

I have following line of code, to understand `async-await` and suspension till awaited task complete.

```
public async Task<string> WaitAsynchronouslyAsync()
    {
        var results = await WaitAsync();
        Console.WriteLine($@"I am not waiting");
        return results;
    }

    public async Task<string> WaitAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(10000).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return "Async programming suspension point demo.";
    }
```

The `await` operator suspends execution until the work of the `WaitAsync()` (Delay 10 seconds) method is complete.

In the meantime, I was expecting that `Console.WriteLine($@"I am not waiting");` should write text to output window until awaited task completes, as control is returned to the caller of `WaitAsync()`. When the task finishes execution, the await expression evaluates string (`"Async programming suspension point demo."`).

> Am I confused here with suspension pointer vs debug pointer?

Comment: You need to turn that into the proper English so that someone can actually understand what happens first. The perfect grammar is not important (I am not perfect either), but one cannot understand important things you try to talk about.

Comment: Remove the `await` from `await WaitAsync();`, move it down to `return (await results);`

Answer (score 8):

> The await operator suspends execution until the work of the WaitAsync()  method is complete.

Correct.

> I was expecting that Console.WriteLine($@"I am not waiting"); should write text to output window until awaited task completes, as control is returned to the caller of WaitAsync().

Why? You just said *the await operator suspends execution until the work is complete*.  The work will not be complete for another ten seconds; the work is *to wait for ten seconds*.  The *work* of `WaitAsync` is not complete until it executes the `return`, and that is in the future.

The right thing to do here is for `WaitAsynchronouslyAsync` to allow *its* caller an opportunity to run in this scenario.

You have correctly stated the meaning of `await`, but you seem to not be fully internalizing the consequences. An `await` checks its operand to see if the task is complete. If it is, then the result of the task is fetched and the method continues. If it is not, then the remainder of the method is signed up as the continuation of that task, and control is yielded so that more work can be done elsewhere. In the future, when the task completes, the remainder of the method is scheduled to execute.

Comment: Yes, I almost got your clarification, however, when you say "control is yielded", does't it mean same, till awaited task completes, here `Task.Delay(10000)`, control yields to calling method and complete other tasks which are not waiting on result awaited method. So `Console.WriteLine($@"I am not waiting")` supposed to be printed.  **OR** simply `await` means simply block the execution of code until task gets complete.

Comment: @AviKenjale I cover the sequence of operations in my answer.  No `await` doesn't block the method, it returns control to the caller and continues executing when the `Task` has finished.

Answer (score 4):

`await` means "wait until this finishes executing asynchronously" your function will not continue until the supplied `Task` finishes executing.

If you instead said the following it wouldn't wait:

```
var results = WaitAsync();
Console.WriteLine($@"I am not waiting");
return await results;
```

Or even more succinctly, remove the `async` from the signature and then you can just `return results;`.

Comment: Yes, this one I tried and works perfectly. However when I read [This Microsoft docs link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await) I got confused with `await` keyword (first 2 paras)

Comment: @AviKenjale: `await` doesn't block the thread but it does block execution of the current method, thus your thread can do other work.

Answer (score 3):

The sequence of operations will go something like this:

1. You call `WaitAsynchronouslyAsync`
2. `WaitAsynchronouslyAsync` calls `WaitAsync`
3. `WaitAsync` calls `Task.Delay(10000).ConfigureAwait(false)`, which produces a `Task`.
4. `WaitAsync` returns a new `Task` to its caller, `WaitAsynchronouslyAsync`, which will be completed later
5. `WaitAsynchronouslyAsync` awaits the task from `WaitAsync`, and then returns to *it's* caller, providing a `Task` representing when it will be finished.
6. Other stuff happens further up the call stack.
7. `Task.Delay` finishes, so the continuation of `WaitAsync` fires, picking up where it left off.
8. `WaitAsync` returns the string, completing the `Task`.
9. `WaitAsynchronouslyAsync` can now continue, since the `Task` returned from `WaitAsync` has finished.  It will go on to print out text to the console.
10. `WaitAsynchronouslyAsync` finishes *it's* task, letting anyone who has anything set up to run when it's finished to be able to run.

Comment: Practically, when cursor hits `await Task.Delay` execution stops there and does't return to calling method.  
I was reading this and confusion started there. [Microsoft docs link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await) - with await keyword (first 2 paras)

Comment: @AviKenjale The debugger isn't going to do that, but that's because it assumes that you don't want to see what's going on further up the call stack, and that you simply want to see what happens after the task finishes and your method is ready to continue.  It's not representative of what's actually being done under the hood.